# Does php have a memory?

Tags: php, memory

I've been programming for almost 3 months, and I've just learned php, and I had a question: Does php have a memory? 
I mean, if I create a new variable using a form, when I'll be refreshing the internet page, will the variable still exists?

Comment: Only if you give it one: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 2):

Yes (and no).

The World Wide Web is basically a [REST implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). This means that the server doesn't remain active to remember the state between requests (it is *stateless*).

And that matches with how PHP runs. A PHP script runs only briefly. The browser requests a url, the PHP script starts, generates output and terminates. Any variables that are in memory are forgotten then.

So if you need to remember something, you have to send it back to the browser, and the browser has to send it back to you again for the next request.

You can do this in a couple of ways.

1. Links. If you output an internal link in PHP, you can add the variable (e.g. 'name') there, so your url becomes `example.com/page.php?name=bob`. This isn't very handy, since there is a lot of garbage in the urls. Moreover, urls with certain values are stored in the history of the browser, so a user can easily and accidentally browse back to a url that has an outdated value for the variable.
2. Cookies. Well known, and much easier and more user friendly than variables in links. You can set a cookie in PHP on the server to send it along with the response to the client (the browser). The browser will send the cookie back with each new request. So you can store your variable in there and it will be preserved. You can set a cookie in PHP using the [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function, and you can read the cookies using the [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

Now, cookies have their limit. They cannot be very large. Also, the variable might contain information that you don't want to send to the browser, because it is classified information.

To solve that, you only need to send a unique code in the cookie, by which you can identify that the next request belongs to the same *session*. Using this *session id*, you can find that variable that was stored on the server alone.

Now, you can implement these sessions yourself, basically as I described. Just generate a unique ID, and store all information you need in a file or in a database, linked to that id. The id is sent to the browser and back using cookies.

But fortunately, PHP can help you with this, and it has a couple of functions that allow you to start a session and remember certain variables until the next request.

It starts with the function [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). With this function, you start a session. PHP will check if the cookies contain a session ID and load the variables of the previous request into the *superglobal* `$_SESSION`. If no session existed, a new unique session id is generated and added to the cookies, and `$_SESSION` is initialized to an empty array.

So after that, you can use that superglobal to store values in:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!array_key_exists('start', $_SESSION))
  $_SESSION['start'] = time(); // Save the start time of the session

echo 'This session started at ' . date($_SESSION['start'])
     . '. And now it is ' . date(time()) . '.';
```

If you open the above script via the browser, and refresh the page, you'll see that the time changes between refreshes, while the original start time is preserved and displayed over and over again. So, while PHP doesn't remember normal variables, you can use *sessions* to preserve specific values.

A detailed description of these features can be found in [PHP: Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: REST is basically a HTTP implementation not vice versa! :) But however +1 for your helpful answer here! You nailed it down

Comment: Thanks! I meant to say, the World Wide Web is a REST implementation. HTTP is the communication protocol, and although HTTP 1.1 and REST are developed together, HTTP was not relevant for that remark.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this through session

```
//set session
session_start();
$_SESSION["test"] = "data33";
```

then,

```
//return session
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["test"];
```

or as "mateop" saied: you can use cookies to store data for longer time :)

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. Otherwise, this is better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, each script execution is independent from the previous. The only way to store variables between executions is to use sessions, cookies or some form of database

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol which means after a page refresh the server does not even remember where did the request came from. -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

To deal with this, we have session - http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php (This link has all the details)

You need to work on these basics and your question shall be answered. Follow the links in this post for a start.

Reference code would be :-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
        echo $_SESSION['var'];
    else
        $_SESSION["var"] = "hello";
?>
```

Comment: *"To deal with this, we have session, cookies or some database method,"* - session is the concept. A cookie is which you store the session id in (even if you use PHP's session function). A database is for server side storage of session information (can be a a file or an actual database). Anyway, there is no 'or' here; they are intertwined.

Comment: And `is_set` should be `isset`.

Comment: Made the required changes. Thanks for reviewing. Appreciate it.